# Select multiple non-sequential lines of code in Rstudio

Tags: rstudio

In `Windows` the user can `select` and `copy` multiple items which are not in sequence by holding down the `Ctrl` key and then selecting each item by either clicking on it or via pressing the `space` followed by the `Ctrl+C` key to copy.

In `RStudio`, how can I select and copy multiple non-sequential lines of code?